# Import .csv file with Chinese characters to Parse

Tags: android, parsing, csv

I want to upload data in a **.csv** file with Chinese character to Parse but after I import, it shows errors saying that all the Chinese characters are invalid and can't be imported.

The error log is here:

> Row 231 is invalid: cannot convert value 'A1' to a number

I check my .csv file in NotePad++ and all the Chinese characters show correctly. Is it because I didn't change the settings in Parse or Parse doesn't support Chinese characters?

Thanks!